# Regex for replacing Exact String match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace below String using replace
Input

```
ABC-9 + ABC-99
```

when I tried to replace only "ABC-9" it also replace "ABC-99".

```
String ExprVal= "(ABC)-9+(ABC)-99";
String Opd = "(ABC)-9"; 
ExprVal = ExprVal.replaceAll("\\b"+Opd+"\\b", 0.0+"");
System.out.println("First replace  "+ExprVal);

ExprVal = ExprVal.replaceAll(Opd, 0.0+"");
System.out.println("Second replace  "+ ExprVal);
```

output:

```
First replace  (ABC)-9+(ABC)-99
Second replace  (ABC)-9+(ABC)-99
Expected ouput   0.0 + (ABC)-99
```

Comment: `.replace` does not work with a regex, you need `.replaceAll`

Comment: i have updated code with replace all

Comment: Sorry, that means it is a dupe of another question. You need to remove the word boundary `\b`, use `Pattern.quote(Opd)` and enclose with `(?<!\w)` / `(?!\w)` - I changed the close reason to a more relevant one.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/Hvf2VD

Comment: I am not able to access u r site. Could you please in example

Comment: `String rx = "(?<!\\w)"+Pattern.quote(Opd)+"(?!\\w)";`

Comment: I do not understand the re-open votes. This is a dupe, isn't it? The solution I provided in my other answer [works fine](https://ideone.com/Hvf2VD), output is `0.0+(ABC)-99`, only exact `(ABC)-9` is replaced with `0.0`. What else is necessary here?

Comment: A [link to rextester](http://rextester.com/WXI68947). Some companies block ideone.com.